# trigger validation before the input is edited

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I have Vue.js 2 project in which I have a `<v-text-field>` component, that is an input field for coordinates and I have vee-validate validation for validating said coordinates, however I have a function `getLatLong` that edits the input to a format I can save. But there is a problem. The validation is validating the already edited format, any idea how to make it work?

This is the text-field:

```html
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="coordinates_validation">
  <v-text-field
    :label="$t('stations.position')"
    :value="positionValue"
    :error-messages="errors"
    @input="$emit('update:station', { ...station, ...getLatLong($event) })"
    @keypress="justNumber"
  />
</ValidationProvider>
```

The text-field is in its own component, because I have more components where it's used

This is the validation-observer:

```html
  <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ invalid }">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline primary white--text"
        >{{ dialogTitle }}
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-text>
        <EditCarModal
          v-if="modal === 'Car'"
          v-model:car="entity"
          :routes="routes"
        />
        <EditRouteModal
          v-else-if="modal === 'Route'"
          v-model:route="entity"
          :stations="stations"
        />
        <EditStationModal v-else v-model:station="entity" />
      </v-card-text>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />

        <v-btn color="error" text @click="resetModal()">
          {{ $t('general.cancel') }}
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          color="success"
          text
          :disabled="
            invalid ||
            (!isUniqNameStation && modal === 'Station') ||
            (!isUniqNameRoute && modal === 'Route') ||
            (!isUniqNameCar && modal === 'Car')
          "
          @click="handleSave()"
        >
          {{ $t('settings.save') }}
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </ValidationObserver>
```

and this is the getLatLong function:

```js
export function getLatLong(position) {
  const latLong = position.split(",");
  if (latLong[0] && latLong[1]) {
    return { latitude: Number(latLong[0]), longitude: Number(latLong[1]) };
  }
  if (!latLong[1] && latLong[0]) {
    return { latitude: Number(latLong[0]), longitude: 0 };
  }
  return { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 };
}
```

I tried to somehow manually trigger the validation before the  getLatLong function is called, however that did not work for me, or I did it incorrectly